# Git manage one project on different remotes with differences

Tags: git

I have a project that runs on 5 different hosts because each customer has it's own. The logic of the application is the same for each applicaion, but the css differs a bit depending on the customers brand colors and stuff like that.

Now I manually manage the upload of the right css file to the right remote host. Is there a way to setup some settings where I can set some specific files for a specific git remote?

So what I want to achieve is that I can do something like this

```
git push remote companyX
git push remote companyY
```

And that the git or something knows what files to push for that specific remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should handle this with git. To manage different css for different host, you can add some code in your application to define an environment (x or y) and base your css choose on that. Something like

```
if env == companyX then
    stylesheet = x.css;
else 
    stylesheet = y.css`.
```

Otherwise, you can use different branches (one per host) and use some complex git-hooks, or use some more complex system with git submodule, but I would not recommend that :)

Comment: Yeah don't want to go too complex for just this kind of stuff, was just wondering if it was easily/good to set it up like this. But I will put that stuff in code. Thanks!

Comment: I usually have a config/[env]/ directory in my projects, that way I can handle different host, or database or other config stuff ( like prod / preprod/ test / staging / local / … )